# how to turn off the log of The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x1bfc) has exited with code 0 (0x0)?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

These information logs are very annoying in the visual studio output.  In java I can just turn the logging level up for that class but how do I turn this off in C# as normal Win32 threads are terminating.  I have log4net in my program so all other logs I can seem to configure.

Comment: There are settings / attributes in log4net where you can set the logging level look in your .Config file <level value="ALL" /> what are your settings..?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Assuming you are talking about messages that appear in Visual Studio's Output window... if you right-click the window, you'll see a menu that looks like this:

[image]

You can turn off Process Exit Messages, Thread Exit Messages, and anything else you don't want to see.

Comment: Is there a way to turn off Thread Exit messages for a particular thread only?